# What's this plant with long pink hanging blossoms?

Tags: identification, flowers

In my garden I have a small bed of flowers pictured below. I don't know what the plant is, so I don't know whether I can move it or not.

The blossoms are long, pink, hang down and almost touch the ground. The stem is also pink. The leaves were much greener than in the images below, but that was before Autumn (Fall) arrived. The roots are relatively poor. It can easily been ripped out of the ground. The plants are 30-50cm (12-18inches) high.

*(Click the images for a larger version)*
**From the top:**                                                           **From the side:**
  
      [image]
  
  
      [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess:

- [Love-Lies-Bleeding - *Amaranthus caudatus*](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/plant-finder/plant-details/kc/a558/amaranthus-caudatus.aspx) via Missouri Botanical Garden
- [*Amaranthus caudatus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranthus_caudatus) via Wikipedia